# Cooking farro in a rice steamer

Tags: grains

Can farro be cooked using a rice steamer?

Would it need to be soaked in water for a period of time first?

Answer (score 1):

It should work, since both are made in a similar manner, rinsed and simmered. If you're using whole grain farro, it does need soaking and longer cooking. I dry-toast the grain in a hot pan before adding the liquid, but that's not required.